# Integration of Docushare with a windows store app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, docushare

Is there anyway to integrate docushare with a windows store app?
I would like to login, get a file/folder list and have the possibility of downloading and uploading files.

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple code snippet which can be good start to play with DocuShare. All possible request can be found in documentation.

Authentication + fetching properties for Collection-11 object

```
    protected const string UsernameFormFieldName = "username";
    protected const string PasswordFormFieldName = "password";
    protected const string DomainFormFieldName = "domain";

    const string CookieName = "AmberUser";
    const string baseAdress = "http://host:port";
    const string container = "/docushare";

    static Uri CookieUrl = new Uri(new Uri(baseAdress), container);

    const string root = "/xcm/v1/shadow/xcmAPI/root";
    const string FolderInfoUri = "/xcm/v1/shadow/object/{0}/xcmAPI/properties";
    const string ObjectVersion = "/xcm/v1/shadow/object/{0}/xcmAPI/version";

    const string ObjectToTest = "Collection-11";

    const string suffix = "?properties=title,mimetype";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var token = Authenticate();
        var requestUri = string.Format(container + FolderInfoUri, ObjectToTest) + suffix;
        var response = GetResult(token, requestUri);
        var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }

    private static string Authenticate()
    {
        const string AuthenticationPath = container + "/dsweb/ApplyLogin";


        var form = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>(UsernameFormFieldName, "login"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>(PasswordFormFieldName, "password"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>(DomainFormFieldName, "domain"),
        });

        string authToken = null;

        Execute((client, handler) =>
        {
            var task = client.PostAsync(AuthenticationPath, form, CancellationToken.None);
            var response = task.Result;
            var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var cookie = handler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(CookieUrl);
            authToken = cookie[CookieName].Value;
        });

        return authToken;
    }

    private static void Execute(Action<HttpClient, HttpClientHandler> request)
    {
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            handler.UseCookies = true;
            handler.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAdress);

            request(client, handler);
        }
    }

    private static HttpResponseMessage GetResult(string token, string uri)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;

        Execute((client, handler) =>
        {
            handler.CookieContainer.Add(
                CookieUrl,
                new Cookie(CookieName, token));

            var responseTask = client.GetAsync(uri);
            response = responseTask.Result;
        });

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: You mentioned "All possible request can be found in documentation" , where is this documentation?

Comment: @Symon you would need to have DSDN Subscription to get access to DocuShare  API documentation.  I do not have access anymore, so I would not be able to give a direct link or hint.

Comment: Aye! That's enough of a hint for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do so with Docushare's HTML/XML API. For details on the Docushare API it looks like you'll need to register for the [DocuShare Developer Network](https://docushare.xerox.com/dsdn/dsweb/HomePage)

Once you know what Docushare expects you should be able to connect to it from your Windows Store app with the [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient) API. See [Connecting to an HTTP server using Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient (XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient)

Comment: i registered and tried to read the documentation on html/xml api, but dindt quite get it :\
any chance you could show a example of a login or a list folders/files ?